# Is it correct if I write: the year will be 2033?

Tags: phrases

Is the phrase above correct? I am not sure about it. Thank you.

It starts with: picture yourself xx years from now: the year will be 2033.

Comment: It's an unusual thing to say, but the question is unanswerable without giving us the context and what you mean by it. If you are simply intending to set a narrative in the future, in the year 2033, then the English convention is that if you use a verb in doing so, you don't use an explicitly future form: either "In the year 2033, ...." or "The year is 2033".

Answer (score 2):

If you are picturing yourself in year 2033, it IS year 2033.  The sentence should read, "Picture yourself XX tears from now; the year is 2033."